# Face recognition with JavaCV

Tags: android, javacv

Has someone successfully implemented the face recognition (thus **not** face detection!) with JavaCV? If yes, can you share your implementation ideas / source codes?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert, but just Googling real quick I found this: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=13. I don't think it's possible to face recognition with JavaCV.

Comment: I have read this article: http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/index.html. The author has implemented this with OpenCV. JavaCV is a port from OpenCV. So I guess or hope that this is possible. And properly I am not the first one that try to do this. Has someone experimented with this in JavaCV?

Answer (score 3):

I ported an OpenCV face recognition example to Java using JavaCV: check [**here**](http://stephenreed.posterous.com/javacv-face-recognition)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am not sure if you got my message on your blog a while back but I have converted used your code in an android application that recognizes faces through the video stream

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but here's a tip:

Remember your "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" must be in the 'src' Folder

This might help you : [cvHaarDetectObjects](http://www.opencv.org.cn/index.php?title=Cv%E6%A8%A1%E5%BC%8F%E8%AF%86%E5%88%AB&variant=zh-tw#cvHaarDetectObjects)

Comment: Isn't the haarcascade for face detection? Which isn't necessary as Android has it's own built in face detection class

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples on opencv installation folder as well and there are lot of examples on face detecting on the internet these are some of them try to go through this links hop you get some idea about it.

- [First](http://tkgospodinov.com/computer-vision-face-detection-in-java-with-opencv-using-javacv/)
- [Second](http://css.dzone.com/articles/face-detection-using-html5)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably well too late, but I figured, just in case anyone else was still wondering I have developed/am still developing a face recognition app on android using JavaCV. It was for a uni project, and it can be found on my git-hub [here](https://github.com/danieljonker/PersonFinder):

I have adapted Stephen Reeds class that he mentioned in his comment to work through Android frames. It is a quite rough around the edges, nowhere near finished, and the facial recognition can only be seen through the log cat as it hasn't got an overlay on top of the camera preview yet. 
But it works.

Hope that helps.